# Creating an "In" Restriction with Linq to NHibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate

Anybody know how I can create an "In" restriction using Linq to NHibernate.

i.e. generate SQL like

select p.Name
from Person p
where p.City In ('London', 'New York', 'Auckland')

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I worked this out. 
Can do:

`from p in session.Query<Person>
 where cities.Contains(p.City)
 select p`

where cities is an array of city names

Anyone know a good reference for Linq to NHibernate examples?

Comment: try also `from p in session.Query<Person> where cities.Any(p.City) select p`